# Can catch block itself be async

Tags: typescript, async-await

```
const x = await function1().catch(async (error) => {
    await function2();
};
```

Is this allowed in typescript? Pretty sure it is, but can't find anything about it. Just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's allowed - but it's sometimes not a great idea for a couple reasons:

- If a Promise awaited inside it throws, you'll have a new error that you'll have to handle for the possibility of with another `.catch`
- Simply returning the Promise of `function2()` inside the `.catch` would accomplish the same thing as making it async

```
const x = await function1()
  .catch(function2)
  // or `.catch(() => function2())` if you want to remove the argument

  .catch(() => {
    // handle function2 throwing
  });
```

Another potential issue is having many possible results for `x` could make its type-checking later difficult. If neither of the `.catch`es evaluate to anything, that's fine - but if `function1` evaluates to something, and you also return something after awaiting `function2`, and you *also* return something after handling the possibility of `function2` throwing - it might be a bit messy to sort out.

Comment: In my real code, I have another line after function2() that takes `error` as parameter. So I think this is the best practice. Otherwise I need to pass the error to the outside.